# Inter-module Communication, Angular Js, Factories

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a simple application that I am developing in Angular. I have simplified the below as much as possible. I am attempting to make a [globally available library injectible](http://jameshill.io/articles/angular-third-party-injection-pattern/) (nothing particularly special):

My `app.module.js` file is defined simply as:

```
angular.module('dogApplication', [
    'dogModule',
    'dogSelection'
]);
```

The `index.html` file is defined as follows (gutted for ease of reading):

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="dogApplication">
    <head>
        <!-- ... -->
        <script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
        <script src="app/dogs/dog.module.js"</script>
        <script src="app/dogs/dog.factory.js"</script>
        <script src="app/dogSelection.module.js"></script>
        <!-- controllers then imported -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- content -->
    </body>
</html>
```

The `.module` files define the modules to which each further component, controller, factory, etc. is attached with `app.module.js` being the "main" module attachment.

`dog.factory.js` is defined as follows:

```
angular
    .module('dogModule')
    .factory('dog', function($window) {
        // do logic defined by James Hill in linked article
        return friendly;
    });
```

I then have a controller:

```
angular
    .module('dogSelection')
    .controller('dogSelectionController', ['$scope', 'dog', function ($scope, dog) {
        if (dog)
        {
            console.log('it worked');
        }
    }])
```

When accessing the application, I get a crummy error message that I can't quite resolve:

```
angular.js:13920 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: dogProvider <- dog <- dogSelectionController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=dogProvider%20%3C-%20dog%20%3C-%20dogSelectionController
    at angular.js:68
    at angular.js:4511
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4664)
    at angular.js:4516
    at getService (angular.js:4664)
    at injectionArgs (angular.js:4688)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4710)
    at $controllerInit (angular.js:10354)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:9263)
    at angular.js:9673
```

With the way I have the above set up, why is the `dog` service *not* available to the `dogSelectionController` via DI?

I know the code in the `.factory( //...` method works as I can attach it to the end of the controller definition; however, I want the factory to be available across the application. Is this possible?

Comment: You've defined it as `leaflet` on the injection array, but then `dog` in the actual parameters. I believe they need to match for things to work.

Comment: @Lex They do not need to match. The only restriction is the name in the string must match the actual name of the service in whatever module it comes from

Comment: @Lex that's a post error, sorry. I need to fix that. Trying to make it more widely applicable.

Comment: Services are shared across the entire app, it doesn't matter which module they belong to. As it was already said, the code has other issues that don't explain what happens but give a hint that something was screwed up. It is a bad practice to use a unit from non-child module. If 'dogSelection' depends on 'dogModule' units (`dog` service), it should state its dependency directly, `angular.module( 'dogSelection', ['dogModule'])`.

Comment: @Lex I agree w/ you 100% about the order that'll definitely lead to some issues

Comment: Also I believe you have a typo `friendly.factory.js` to `dog.factory.js`

Answer (score 0):

First issue I see is you need an array after module. **Even if there are no module dependencies.** So it's `.module('dogSelection', [])` not `.module('dogSelection')` - Next issue I see is you need to define the module dog uses before injecting it. Without a module that defines where dob comes from dog will throw an error like your seeing. Something like this

Module:

```
angular.module('dogModule', [])

.factory('dog', function($window) 
{

});
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('dogSelection', [
  'dogModule'
])

.controller('dogSelectionController', ['$scope', 'dog', function ($scope, dog) 
{

}]);
```

Comment: The module is declared elsewhere. The inclusion of `[]` here overrides the module. Again, the definitions happen elsewhere as per the OP (excluded for brevity; take not of `index.html`)

Comment: @Thomas Sorry I read your post a bit too fast and the leaflet through me off. I think what I've got now might be what ur lookin for

Comment: No problem. Working through it now. I'm getting all sorts of funky errors, now. I have no idea what I am doing "wrong". Agh.

Comment: @Thomas That's frustrating. If you put the full code blocks in a fiddle or codepen (even if it doesen't run that's okay) I can edit the module definition pieces for ya!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `'dogSelectionController'` injector should be changed from `['$scope', 'leaflet'` to `['$scope', 'dog'`. The dog factory is not named `'leaflet'`.

Update:

As a workaround for shared factories is to have the factories on the main app module directly.
I'm on my mobile now so will not be able to give a better answer at the moment.

Comment: Updated question. Thanks.